# Problem trying to insert a value from a query with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to select and insert values into a database with eloquent models. The thing is, i made a query to get a value from another table and insert it in the new one. But it keeps inserting 0 when it should insert the value of the  id that i'm  retrieving

This is the way i'm selecting the id from table clients:

```
$client_id = Client::select('id')->where('dni', '=', $request->client)->first();
        \Log::debug($client_id);
```

The debug on the Log returns this:

```
[2020-08-05 17:43:25] local.DEBUG: {"id":1}
```

And this is the insert:

```
$seguro = new Seguro();

        $seguro->usuario_id = $user_id;
        $seguro->cliente_id = $client_id;
$seguro->save();
```

And the insert is successfull except for the column cliente_id where i'm getting 0 instead of 1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $client_id contains object (model), not integer value. You can even see this in debug. Just get id from this model using `->id`

```
$seguro->cliente_id = $client_id->id; // also better change name $client_id to $client
```

or

```
$client_id = Client::select('id')->where('dni', '=', $request->client)->first()->id;
```

Also it is good idea to write code in english (variable names). For example I do not know what "dni" should mean in this query.

Comment: Ok that worked, i completely missed it. The english part, yes, it's true, but in this case i have to follow the normative of an API that's written in spanish so... it sucks, but thank you so much!